# Write multiple .csv files

Tags: matlab

I have a cell array in `Matlab` (1x149): each cell containing data from a separate `.txt` file. I used the following code to load the `.txt` files

```
d = dir('*.txt');
nfiles = length(d);
data = cell(1, nfiles);
for k = 1:nfiles
data{k} = importdata(d(k).name);
end
```

Columns 1 through 5

```
[39676x182 double]    [39676x182 double]    [39676x182 double]    [39676x182 double]    [39676x182 double]
```

I want to write individual .csv files for each cell.

I tried using `csvwrite`, but it gives a large file which I can't really work with. I am trying to write a `for` loop to write each cell to a separate CSV file

Comment: You have tagged this as both `R` and `matlab`, so you really need to tell us which language you are using.  Since you called it a cell array, I assume it is `matlab`, but you need to include that in your question and remove the `r` tag if it isn't relevant.  Also include the things you have already tried (but didn't work) to accomplish this.  Hint: start with `csvwrite`.

Comment: What happened when you tried to put `csvwrite` in a loop?

Comment: I don't know if this is the right approach but this is what I have: `for i = 1:10
csv(i)=csvwrite('test%d.csv',data(i:i))
end` the error i get is too many output arguments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just tried this and generated some random numbers which fit your problem.

```
test = mat2cell(randi(50,39676*5,182),[39676,39676,39676,39676,39676],182);
test = test';
```

Gives me:

```
test = 

    [39676x182 double]    [39676x182 double]    [39676x182 double]    [39676x182 double]    [39676x182 double]
```

Looping through this with:

```
 for i = 1:5
    csvwrite(strcat('file',num2str(i),'.csv'),test{1,i})
 end
```

Results in five *.csv Files (file1.csv, file2.csv, ...). Using strcat to get file name could be solved better, but i dont know how.